# How is called this way of express complex numbers and how to convert to polar form?

Tags: complex-numbers

[expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE3ii.png)

I am trying to solve some electronics problems in this [site](http://tuttle.merc.iastate.edu/ee201/practice/complex_math.php) and I faced with some complex numbers math problems which the answer is in a syntax that are incomprehensible to me.

I was able to find the answer in polar form. But as a matter of comparation, i cannot check my answer with the site answer.

I will take a example. I faced a problem where the expected response was 19.exp(-j120º). But I only achieve the results in polar form.

That is, I cannot transform 19.exp(-j120º) in polar form or vice-versa. Moreover, I don't have idea what this extended form be like.

Any hint in how to do it?

Comment: The central dot is the usual product.

Comment: $\exp$ is the exponential function; $\exp(x)=e^x$, where $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- $\renewcommand{Re}{\operatorname{Re}}\renewcommand{Im}{\operatorname{Im}}$The central dot is the usual product on $\Bbb C$. Namely, $z\cdot w$ is the complex number such that $$\Re(z\cdot w)= (\Re z)(\Re w)-(\Im z)(\Im w)\\ \Im(z\cdot w)=(\Re z)(\Im w)+(\Re w)(\Im z)$$ Just like with the product on $\Bbb R$, you would often not write the dot altogether when letters are involved.
- $\exp$ is the [exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Complex_plane). Often you may find $e^z$ instead of $\exp(z)$.